# Problema com git stash save --keep-index e git pull

Tags: python, git

estou tentando dar git pull em um servidor mas ele pede para salvar os arquivos e mesmo usando o comando "git stash save --keep-index" (sempre funcionou) ele não deixa eu executar o git pull

Comment: Qual a mensagem que aparece quando você tenta executar o `git pull`?

Comment: error: Your local changes to the following files would be overwritten by merge:
        aurerioGame/__pycache__/settings.cpython-36.pyc
Please, commit your changes or stash them before you can merge.
Aborting

Comment: A mensagem não diz tudo? Ao invés de manter o index, é só você voltá-lo para o estado anterior. Só remover o --keep-index